# Series, divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^4-3n}{n^5+n}$

I want to show, that this series is divergent, but i can not find a divergent minorant...

I tried

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^4-3n}{n^5+n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^3-3}{n^4+1}\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^3}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$

But that is wrong, i think. I have to find a minorant and not a majorant.

If someone could help me, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 2$, we have $n^4-3n\ge \frac{n^4}{2}$.

Also, $n^5+n\le 2n^5$.

Thus for $n\ge 2$, our function is $\ge \frac{1}{4n}$.

Comment: So I have this $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^4-3}{n^5+n}$ and so the series is divergent?

Comment: Not quite. In the answer above, I wrote that the inequality holds if $n\ge 2$. However, convergence/divergence is unaffected by first few (or first few thousand!) terms. If you started the sums in your comments at $n=2$, everything would be correct.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I love you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, You can use the
**Limit Comparison Test**

$$\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n, \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} b_n, \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \ne 0$$ 
With $a_n$ and $b_n$ series with positive terms;

If $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} b_n$ converges/diverges, $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges/diverges respectively.

---

$$a_n = \frac{n^4 - 3n}{n^5 + n} = \frac{n^4}{n^5} \cdot \frac{1 - 3n/n^4}{1 + n/n^5} \approx \frac{1}{n}$$
($\frac{3n}{n^4}$ and $\frac{n}{n^5}$ $\to 0$ for $n$ very, very large)

Take $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4 - 3n}{n^5 + n} \cdot n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^5 - 3n^2}{n^5 + n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^5/n^5 - 3n/n^5}{n^5/n^5 + n/n^5} = \frac{1+0}{1+0} = 1 \ne 0$$

$\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges since its a p-series with $p = 1$.

Since all the criteria is met and $\sum b_n (\frac{1}{n})$ diverges, $\sum \frac{n^4 - 3n}{n^5 + n}$ diverges.